# EigenValue and Basis Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> The matrix
>   $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 3 & 3 \\ -3 & -6 & -3 \\ 3 & 3 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ has two real eigenvalues, one of multiplicity $1$ and one of multiplicity $2$. Find the eigenvalues and a basis of each eigenspace.

I have found that $\det(A−λI)= -λ^3 -6λ^2 -27$. But I'm having a hard time factoring this cubic equation. Any hints?

Comment: $$|A - \lambda I| = 0 \implies -\lambda ^3-6 \lambda ^2-9 \lambda = 0 \implies  -\lambda  (\lambda +3)^2 = 0$$

Comment: yours is 9 mine is 27

Comment: Always try the rational-root test: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/rtnlroot2.htm

Comment: @MaxDCaliss: Actually, mine is $9 \lambda$, which makes a world of difference. Check your algebra, bet there is a simple issue.

Comment: Heres what I did , -λ|(6λ+λ2)-(3*-3)| - 3(3λ-(-9)) = -λ3-6λ2-9λ-9λ+27 I did something wrong somewhere but I can't figured it out

Comment: @MaxDCaliss were you trying to expand along the first row? shouldn't it consist of $3$ terms rather than $2$?

Comment: Figured it out it was minor algebra error , thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $$R_1+R_3=-R_2$$

where $R_i$ denotes the $i$-th row of the matrix. Hence $0$ must be an eigenvalue and you must have made some computational mistake.

Also, $R_1$ and $R_3$ are not scalar multiple of each other, hence the rank of matrix is at least $2$.

Hence multiplicity of eigenvalue $0$ must be $1$ and we have another eigenvalue, $\alpha$ with multiplicty $2$.

$$tr(A)=-6$$

$$0+2\alpha = -6$$

$$\alpha = -3$$

Comment: Why is it clear that $\alpha$ has multiplicitiy $2$? How did we rule out the existence of a third eigenvalue $\beta \neq \alpha$?

Comment: @Roland In general, you can’t conclude this, but in the problem statement we’re given that one of the eigenvalues has multiplicity 2.

Comment: Sometimes, reading the problem statement thoroughly is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the characterist equation just gets in the way.

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 &3 &3\\-3&-6&-3\\3&3&0\end{bmatrix}$

The 1 column + 3rd colum - second column produces a zero vector.

$A$ is singular.
$\det (A) = 0.$
$0$ is an eigenvalue.

$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector

$(A-\lambda I) = \begin{bmatrix} -\lambda &3 &3\\-3&-6-\lambda&-3\\3&3&-\lambda\end{bmatrix}$

Just looking at the first and 3rd rows.
$\lambda = -3$ is going to make those two rows equal and hence 
$\det(A + 3I) = 0$

$(A+3I) = \begin{bmatrix} 3 &3 &3\\-3&-3&-3\\3&3&3\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\\0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$  are eigenvectors

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Given
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 0 & 3 & 3 \\
 -3 & -6 & -3 \\
 3 & 3 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
resolve the eigensystem.

### Solution

Find the eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenvectors.

**Eigenvalues**

Use the cofactor expansion to find the eigenvalues. Let
$$
 \mathbf{W} = \mathbf{A} - \lambda \mathbf{I}_{3}
$$
The characteristic polynomial is
$$
\begin{align}
%
 p(\lambda) &= \det \mathbf{W} \\ 
%
&=
%
 0 \det \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\lambda -6 & -3 \\
 3 & -\lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
-3 \det \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -3 & -3 \\
 3 & -\lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
+6 \det \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -3 & -\lambda -6 \\
 3 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
%
&= 9 \lambda - 27
%
\end{align}
%
$$
Using the succinct argument of @Siong Thye Goh, the eigenvalue spectrum is
$$
\boxed{
  \lambda \left( \mathbf{A} \right) = \left\{ -3, -3, 0 \right\}
}
$$

(Notice the *a priori* insights in his post reveal we won't need to solve a cubic equation.)

**Eigenvectors** $\lambda = -3$

Find the eigenvectors $w$ which satisfy
$$
\begin{align}
%
  \left( \mathbf{A} - \lambda \mathbf{I}_{3} \right) w &= \mathbf{0}\\
%
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 -3 & -3 & -3 \\
 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
w &=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{array}
\right)
%
\end{align}
$$

Method: find the null space of $\left( \mathbf{A} - \lambda \mathbf{I}_{3} \right)^{*}$.

*Clear column 1*

$$
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{crc|ccc}
 3 & -3 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 3 & -3 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 3 & -3 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 \boxed{1} & -1 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\\hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
$$

The two eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $\lambda = -3$ are
$$
\boxed{
w_{1} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{array} \right],
\qquad
w_{2} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{array} \right]
}
$$

**Eigenvectors** $\lambda = 0$

Find the null space of $\mathbf{A}^{*}$.

*Clear column 1*

$$
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 0 & -3 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 3 & -6 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 3 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 3 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 3 & -6 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -3 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
$$

$$
%
\left(
\begin{array}{rcc}
 \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 3 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 3 & -6 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -3 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccr}
 \boxed{1} & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
 0 & -3 & 3 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
 0 & -3 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
$$

*Clear column 2*

$$
%
\left(
\begin{array}{rrc}
 -3 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccr}
 \boxed{1} & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
 0 & -3 & 3 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
 0 & -3 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccr}
 \boxed{1} & 0 & -1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} \\
 0 & \boxed{1} & -1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\\hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
$$
The eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda = 0$ is
$$
\boxed{
u = 
\left[ \begin{array}{r}
 1 \\ -1 \\ 1
\end{array} \right]
}
$$